# A variant of the inverse Galois problem

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, galois-representations

In Theorem I of [Construction of maximal unramified p-extensions with prescribed Galois groups](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-010-0289-0), it's proved that

> for any prime $p$ and any given finite $p$-group $G$, there exists a number field $F$ such that the Galois group of the maximal unramified $p$-extension over $F$ is isomorphic to $G$.

It leads to the following question:

> Question: Let $G$ be a finite group. Is there a number field $F$ such that the Galois group $G_{F,\emptyset}$ of the maximal unramified extension over $F$ is isomorphic to $G$?

To my knowledge, it is not known that whether there exist infinitely many number field $F$ such that $G_{F,\emptyset}$ is finite. So trying to give an affirmative answer to the above question is hopeless. But I'm more inclined to believe the answer to the question should be NO. Maybe someone has a counterexample?

Comment: A streamlined proof of the result you cite is given here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2204.08408